# XCode 7 Custom Templates: Change Build Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode-template

I am creating a custom `XCode` project template following [this](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-create-custom-project-templates-in-xcode-7) tutorial.

I am able to set build settings with **FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS** but its not working with **GCC_PREFIX_HEADER** or **LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS**.
I tried many different solutions but its not working for any flag except FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS.

Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong here.
Thanks in advance!!

Here is what I've done so far.

```
// Working

<key>Targets</key>
<array>
        <dict>
        <key>SharedSettings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS</key>
            <array>
                <string>$(PROJECT_DIR)</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

---

```
// Not working

<key>Targets</key>
<array>
        <dict>
        <key>SharedSettings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS</key>
            <array>
                <string>$(inherited)</string>
                <string>Users/Name/Desktop/MyFrameworkDirectory</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

---

```
// Not working

<key>Targets</key>
<array>
        <dict>
        <key>SharedSettings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER</key>
            <true/>
            <key>GCC_PREFIX_HEADER</key>
            <string>MyFile.pch</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
            <key>SharedSettings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>GCC_PREFIX_HEADER</key>
            <string>___PACKAGENAME___/MyFile.pch</string>
        </dict>
```

Use this syntax instead.

And for the LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS you should use one of the executables from [Please Click here](https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath) or [Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html).

For Example, I have Used @executable_path (@loader_path will also work)

```
        <key>LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS</key>
        <string>$(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks @executable_path/../Frameworks</string>
```